# Finding the irreducible representation of Kraus operators of a dephasing channel

Tags: error-correction, quantum-operation, decoherence, kraus-representation

I would like to understand an example of finding a noiseless subsystem of a quantum channel from the irreducible representation of its Kraus operators.

Assume we have $2$ dephasing channels acting on two qubits, then
$$\mathcal{E}(\rho_{AB})= \sum_{i=1}^4 K_i \rho_{AB} K_i^\dagger,$$
where the Kraus operators are
$$K_1=\mathbf{1}_{AB}/2,
\qquad K_2= \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{1}_{A}\otimes Z_B,
\qquad K_3=\frac{1}{2}Z_A\otimes \mathbf{1}_{B},
\qquad K_4=\frac{1}{2}Z_{A}\otimes Z_B.$$
How do I decompose this as $\bigoplus_j \mathbf{1}_{n_j}\otimes M(d_j) $? Will each Kraus operator be expressible in this decomposition?

I can see they are diagonal, and this channel has three decoherence-free subspaces; one spanned by $|00\rangle$,  one spanned by $|11\rangle$,and one spanned by $\{|01\rangle,|10\rangle\}$.
As mentioned in this [book](https://books.google.ch/books?id=XV9sAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=daniel%20lidar%20noiseless%20product,%20and%20this%20does%20not%20have%20to%20be%20a%20subspace%20(e.g.,%20in%20general%20it%20is%20not%20closed%20under%20addition)&source=bl&ots=zs7Tt3rlYN&sig=ACfU3U06N1o2GSgaBa8Ho72Q7QHa03mNrA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhganBgpvrAhXCyaQKHbhOBP8Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=daniel%20lidar%20noiseless%20product%2C%20and%20this%20does%20not%20have%20to%20be%20a%20subspace%20(e.g.%2C%20in%20general%20it%20is%20not%20closed%20under%20addition)&f=false), decoherence free subspaces are a special case of noiseless subsystems, where $M(d_j)$ is just a constant, and $n_j$ is the dimension of the decoherence-free subspace. How do I extract these $n_j$'s from the Kraus operators or their irreps?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the form you write these are not Kraus operators. Also, what is the "irreducible representation of Kraus operators" - it would be good if you could define this.

Comment: I normalized them, so I believe now they should be correct? 
What I mean is that, technically the 'algebra of Kraus operators is isomorphic to a direct sum of irreducible representations', which I think means each of the Kraus operators can be expressed by a block diagonal matrix of the form $\bigoplus \mathbf{1}_{n_j} \otimes  M(d_j)$ , where $M(d_j)$ is some complex matrix.

Comment: The formula for E(rho) you write is not a Kraus form. Also, I'd say that a map with these Kraus operators does not have dec. free subspaces with dimension >1.

Comment: I see, may be I am confused between the dephasing channel and the collective dephasing  where $|{0}\rangle$ is unaffected, and $|{1}\rangle$ is mapped to $e^{i\phi} |1\rangle$. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I think it is very confusing that your tensor product is not always ordered the same way (i.e. A x B).

Comment: ... and as I said before: Why do you think that the space {|01>,|10>} is decoherence free?  Wouldn't e.g. |01>+|10> decohere?

Comment: I just confused the dephasing channel (I+Z) with the collective dephasing $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & e^{j\phi} 
\end{bmatrix}$ which does have these DFSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear up my own confusion, these DFSs exist for the channel that maps $|0\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ to $e^{j\phi}|1\rangle$. This is not the channel discussed in the question.